Generating PDF/A-3A with mPDF Library in PHP
I’m trying to generate a PDF/A-3A document using the mPDF library in PHP, but I keep getting a PDF/A-1B output instead. Here’s the code I’m using:
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'margin_left' => 4,
            'margin_right' => 4,
            'margin_top' => 42,
            'margin_bottom' => 20,
            'margin_header' => 32,
            'margin_footer' => 17,
            'default_font' => 'Myriad Pro',
            'default_font_size' => 8,
        ]);

$mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', "url('./backgroundimage.jpeg')");
        $mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image-resize', 6); 
        
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
    $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeaderByName('Header');
    // Decode the XML content from base64
    $xmlDecodedContent = base64_decode($xmlEncodeValue);

    // Sanitize $invoiceNo to avoid issues with special characters
    $sanitizedInvoiceNo = preg_replace('/[^\w-]/', '_', $invoiceNo);
    $customTempDir = 'pdf_attachments';
    // Ensure directory exists
    if (!file_exists($customTempDir)) {
        mkdir($customTempDir, 0777, true); // Create directory if it doesn't exist
    }

    // Create a temporary file path for the XML (stored in the system's temporary directory)
    $xmlTempFilePath = $customTempDir . '/invoice_' . $sanitizedInvoiceNo . '.xml';

    // Save the XML content to the temporary file
    file_put_contents($xmlTempFilePath, $xmlDecodedContent);

    // Embed the temporary XML file into the PDF
    $mpdf->SetAssociatedFiles([[
        'name' => 'invoice_' . $sanitizedInvoiceNo . '.xml', // The name that will be shown in the PDF
        'mime' => 'text/xml', // MIME type
        'description' => 'Invoice XML file', // File description
        'AFRelationship' => 'Data', // Relationship to the PDF
        'content' => $xmlDecodedContent // Content of the XML file
    ]]);
    $rdf  = '<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:zf="urn:ferd:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#">'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:DocumentType>INVOICE</zf:DocumentType>'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:DocumentFileName>ZUGFeRD-invoice.xml</zf:DocumentFileName>'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:Version>1.0</zf:Version>'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:ConformanceLevel>BASIC</zf:ConformanceLevel>'."\n";
$rdf .= '</rdf:Description>'."\n";

$mpdf->SetAdditionalXmpRdf($rdf);

if (file_exists($xmlTempFilePath)) 
{
 unlink($xmlTempFilePath); // Delete the temp file
}
$mpdf->WriteHTML( $htmlContent);
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooterByName('Footer');
    

ob_clean(); 
$mpdf->Output('invoice_' . $sanitizedInvoiceNo . '.pdf', 'I');


Current Output:
Standard: PDF/A-1B
ISO Name: ISO 19005-1
Status: not yet verified
Output Intent
Identifier: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Info: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Desired Output:
Standard: PDF/A-3A
ISO Name: ISO 19005-3
Status: not yet verified
Output Intent
Identifier: Custom
Info: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Question:
What adjustments do I need to make to my code to ensure that the generated PDF adheres to the PDF/A-3A standard instead of PDF/A-1B? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
The reason why I need my PDFs to comply with the PDF/A-3A standard is that I am working on ZATCA E-invoicing Integration Phase 2 in Saudi Arabia. According to the regulations, tax invoices or their associated notes must be generated electronically and shared with customers either in XML format or in PDF/A-3 format with embedded XML files. The PDF/A-3 standard is crucial because it allows embedding the XML data directly into the PDF document, ensuring compliance with the e-invoicing regulations while maintaining accessibility and archiving capabilities. Therefore, the use of PDF/A-3A helps meet these regulatory requirements effectively.

Does mpdf plan to support PDF/A-3? https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/discussions/1568

@KIKOSoftware Then Can you suggest any php pdf library that supports PDF/A-3A

I don't know any. Note that your question would be easier to answer if you added the reason why you want your PDF's to use the PDF/A-3A standard. Do you want to attach files? Does the receiver of the PDF file demand this? Or just for fun?

From what I can find any library can be extended to comply with the PDF/A-3A standard, but it requires quite a bit of programming skills. In other words: There doesn't seem to be an easy solution.

@KIKOSoftware The reason why I need my PDFs to comply with the PDF/A-3A standard is that I am working on ZATCA E-invoicing Integration Phase 2 in Saudi Arabia. According to the regulations, tax invoices or their associated notes must be generated electronically and shared with customers either in XML format or in PDF/A-3 format with embedded XML files. The PDF/A-3 standard is crucial because it allows embedding the XML data directly into the PDF document, ensuring compliance with the e-invoicing regulations while maintaining accessibility and archiving capabilities.

@KIKOSoftware thanks for the suggestion i will add it now to my post

I did find this example for adding files to a mPDF file. It might be what you're looking for, but I can't be sure, of course.

@KIKOSoftware You mentioned that any PDF library can be extended to comply with the PDF/A-3A standard and achieve my requirements. Could you suggest any reference code or threads related to this?

@KIKOSoftware I tried this solution, and the XML is attached correctly within the PDF. However, the document format is still Standard: PDF/A-1B (ISO 19005-1). I need it to be Standard: PDF/A-3A (ISO 19005-3).

Yes, it would still be PDF/A-1B, but now with files attached. Did you test whether this would be acceptable to the ZATCA E-invoicing system, or did you just look in the file? Sorry, I have to leave now and haven't got time to research this further. I only saw hint of people suggesting that you can create this extension yourself, I didn't dive into it at all.

As far as I know, ZATCA's e-invoicing documentation only specifies that the invoice must be in PDF/A-3A format with the XML attached. There's no direct way to test PDF compliance with ZATCA, but we've already sent the XML through their API and received a successful response. Explaining the whole process would take time. Thanks a lot for your help
